# Mapping JPA columns to EnumMap

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

**The problem**

I am struggling with mapping multiple database columns to a single `Map`, where the column name is the key (as an enum), and the column value is the floating-point value.

For example, given the following database table:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.0 | 2.0 | 3.0 |

I would like to be able to do (something like) the following:

```java
public enum MyEnum {
  A,
  B,
  C;
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

  Map<MyEnum, Float> myMap;

}
```

And have the myMap automatically instantiated, so that:

```java
myMap == Map.of(MyEnum.A, 1.0f, MyEnum.B, 2.0f, MyEnum.C, 3.0f);
```

**Motivation**

I have multiple database tables with a large number of columns, where each column represents the floating-point value of an enumerable field. I would like to automatically map all of these columns to a java `Map`, so that later on I can easily iterate through them for processing.

**What I tried**

Using `@PostLoad` and manually mapping the table. It didn't work well because the entity has a very large number of fields, and having to specify them one by one anyway defeats the purpose.

**Other**

I am not sure if any of this helps, but:

- The project uses JPA in Spring Boot.
- The project uses JDK 17.
- The database is PostgreSQL.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: _"tables with a large number of columns, where each column represents the floating-point value of an enumerable field"_ - Ouch! Bad design.  Do you have control over the database schema? If so, normalize it.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I do have control over it, but I am not sure how can I break it down further: the columns represent the individual dimensions of a 50-dimensional embedding, so they are, technically, "one thing". Would it be better to stop trying to do what I am doing, and instead store the embedding directly as JSON? Or am I still looking at this the wrong way?

Comment: Can't you store the key-value pair as a JSON object in a single column [if it meets your database design purpose]? Then you can easily serialize or deserialize the key-value with a DTO or a mapper class.

Comment: I tried doing that, and it works perfectly! It's infinitely cleaner and much simpler to work with. Thank you both so much for your help - I really appreciate it.